# Any alternatives to cmd.exe or JP Software's Take Command?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, powershell

I know of PowerShell and something similar to it, but specifically I want JP Software's Take Command program, however it costs $100 for the full version. Is there any way to obtain Take Command either at a discounted price or free? I am also open to any low cost or free alternatives with similar features.

Comment: Any specific features you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but asking for cracked version is not allowed here. Try NirCmd:

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html

> NirCmd is a small command-line utility that allows you to do some
>   useful tasks without displaying any user interface. By running NirCmd
>   with simple command-line option, you can write and delete values and
>   keys in the Registry, write values into INI file, dial to your
>   internet account or connect to a VPN network, restart windows or shut
>   down the computer, create shortcut to a file, change the
>   created/modified date of a file, change your display settings, turn
>   off your monitor, open the door of your CD-ROM drive, and more...

it is freeware after offers a lot of useful commands.